# Gem Chartkick charts not rendering on PDF

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf, chartkick

I'm using Rails 5.2.4, Gem Chartkick(3.3.1) and wicked_pdf(1.4.0).
As many people wrote, I can also not display a pie chart on pdf through Chartkick and wicked_pdf, just "loading" is shown.
The chart is correctly showing on html.

If someone could already solve this problem, please let me know which version of Chartkick and wicked_pdf was used?

I tried as below but no success:

1. Add into box_report.pdf.erb

```
<%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "application", "chartkick" %>
```

2. Add into controller

```
window_status: "FLAG_FOR_PDF"
```

plus add into application.js

```
setTimeout((function () {
    window.status = "FLAG_FOR_PDF";
    Object.keys(Chartkick.charts).forEach(function (key) {
        Chartkick.charts[key].redraw();
    });
}), 3000);
```

3. Add wicked_pdf.rb

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  javascript_delay: 3000,
...
}
```

4. Add into controller

```
javascript_delay: 3000,
```

Comment: I'm on the same page here. Tried everything on the internet. Nothing seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying Pie chart you need to use `<%= pie_chart #count, width, height, id, and other options goes here %>`. Make sure to use it in the template file you will be using.